# android - инициализация Realm

Tags: android, база-данных, realm-android

Делаю все по офф докам, хочу подключить к проекту realm
билдится нормально, но при открытии приложения вылетает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer, PID: 30745
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: RealmTransformer doesn't seem to be applied. Please update the project configuration to use the Realm Gradle plugin. See https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/
                      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.<clinit>(RealmConfiguration.java:77)
                      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.initializeBuilder(RealmConfiguration.java:414)
                      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:402)
                      at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:189)
                      at ru.webant.projects.dossier.downloadFile.DownloadManager.onCreate(DownloadManager.java:38)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4572)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5275)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

ссылка падает на строку:

```
Realm.init(this);
```

инициализирую в классе, который прописан в манифесте в разделе application. то есть в том, в котором инициализирую и firebase и остальное:

```
public class DownloadManager extends Application {
public static Context CONTEXT;
private final static String TAG = "FileDownloadApplication";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CONTEXT = this;
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notification");
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("file_models.realm").build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
```

build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
}
} 

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.liulishuo.filedownloader:library:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'cn.dreamtobe.threaddebugger:threaddebugger:1.3.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

никак не могу решить эту проблему! буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Realm [не работает](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3038) с Jack (пока). Придется выбрать что то одно - или Java 8 или Realm. Связано с конфликтом процессинга аннотаций, вроде. Так же будут конфликты и с другими библиотеками, которые используют такие механизмы

Comment: я более того скажу, jack вообще больше не поддерживается, гугл отказались от него. чтобы не было полезненных изменений, советую просто переключиться на ретролямбду и все.