# Android приложение падает при инициализации Realm

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

Android приложение падает при инициализации Realm.

В Android Monitor ошибка:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: RealmTransformer doesn't seem to be applied. Please update the project configuration to use the Realm Gradle plugin. See https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/

Realm подключен согласно инструкции с сайта Realm.io.

build.gradle (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.levelp.chatlevelup_11_12"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Проект целиком, на всякий случай: https://github.com/miller7777777/Level_Up_chat_11_12

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647002/177345

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно en-so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153879/realm-android-realmtransformer-doesnt-seem-to-be-applied у вас конфлик с jack.

Т.е. вам надо удалить поддержу jack.

```
jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
```

Comment: Rettolambda у вас также не заработает если вы не укажите совместимость с 8 явой. Смотрите доку к ретролямбде раздел андроид

Comment: Благодарю, помогло, хотя по началу запутался.

Comment: @Miller777, если ответ помог решить проблему, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галку слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Я, могу ошибаться, но при использовании sugar orm была такая же ерунда. Мне помогло отключение настройки в андроид Студио https://stackoverflow.com/a/36598402

Comment: Помогло удаление jack из build.gradle, но ваш случай я буду иметь ввиду на случай подобных граблей.